# Sql query join?

Tags: sql

I have one table containing car inventory. This has two columns one is car_id and the other is car_info e.g. bmw 320

The other table also contains a table with two columns. One is sales_ids and the other is car_id they have sold.

I want to create an sql query were the output will be the sales_id and the car name which was sold by that sales_id.

I have tried using a join query but have had no sucess thus far. Can anyone offer some help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select s.sales_id, i.car_info
  from inventory i
  join sales s on s.car_id = i.car_id;
```

To find cars sold for one specific sales_id:

```
select i.car_info
  from inventory i
  join sales s on s.car_id = i.car_id
 where s.sales_id = 'some id';
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to choose the sales_id .. so            'select s.sales_id='sales1', i.car_info
  from inventory i
  join sales s on s.car_id = i.car_id' - This doesnt work BTW

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.car_id,c.car_info,s.sales_id from
     car_table_name c,
     sales_table_name s
where c.car_id = s.car_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table one is named **car_inventory** and table two **car_sales** the query should be this.

However for a better answer you should provide the code you try with your question.

```
select car_sales.sales_ids, car_inventory.car_info 
from car_sales join car_inventory 
on car_sales.car_id = car_inventory.car_id
```